Setting signal input on a component in ng boostrap modal
In Angular 17.3, I have a component that is using some signal inputs, like
myInput = input(false);

I want to show this component in a modal, using ng-bootstrap. Is it possible to do this, and set the value of myInput? I have tried
private modalService = inject(NgbModal);

const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyComponent);
modalRef.componentInstance.myInput = true;

as shown in the bootstrap documentation, but this seems to override the field myInput to turn it into a boolean instead of a signal. I tried
modalRef.componentInstance.myInput.set(true);

but it says "modalRef.componentInstance.myInput.set is not a function".
Is this at all possible? or it's just not compatible with signals?

sorry for the oversight, it is input(false), thx

Since input cannot be modified, you should either use a signal or a model, which can be modified.
If you need the component to accept inputs [someInputSignal]="'test'" and be updatable by ng-bootstrap go for modal ( until input signal setInput is supported), if not use an ordinary signal
Model inputs - Signals
We can set the model to accept inputs
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        {{someInputSignal()}}
    `,
})
export class NgbdModalContent {  
  someInputSignal: ModelSignal<string> = model('');
  ...
}

Then on the open method use set to set the value of the signal.
    open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
        const comp: NgbdModalContent = modalRef.componentInstance;
        comp.someInputSignal.set('it works!');
    }

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  inject,
  input,
  ModelSignal,
  InputSignal,
  Input,
  signal,
  model,
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        {{someInputSignal()}}
    `,
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  activeModal = inject(NgbActiveModal);

  someInputSignal: ModelSignal<string> = model('');
  @Input() some: string = '';

  ngOnInit() {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './modal-component.html',
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  private modalService = inject(NgbModal);

        open() {
            const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
            const comp: NgbdModalContent = modalRef.componentInstance;
            comp.someInputSignal.set('it works!');
        }
}

Stackblitz Demo

very nice, I didn't know about model before

I don't think that model is the best choice here, because it's designed for two-way binding.

@Guillaume If you need the component to accept inputs [someInputSignal]="'test'" and be updatable by ng-bootstrap go for modal ( until input setInput is supported), if not use an ordinary signal

Yes I understand that, but I actually want to keep the ability to create my component in html like <my-component [myInput]="true" />, so using amodel is the best solution. Otherwise I would just use a signal for sure

By design, signal inputs are readonly. You can only set a new value via binding in the template, or via ComponentRef.setInput(). Unfortunately, ng-bootstrap does not expose the ComponentRef, but there is a feature request to add it. Until then, you can use a bare signal() which is writable, or a decorator-based @Input().
